# How to catch component unmount caused by live reload

Tags: react-native

[edit - I thought I was using Hot Reloading, but I am actually using Live Reload]

I have a native plugin that needs to do some clean up each time it is finished with. Basically I want to prevent these errors:

```
Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit(..)
```

componentWillUnmount() doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

**Live reloading** will restart the app and load the app back to the initial route when a file changes. ComponentWillUnmount won't be called.

When you reload, what happens behind the scenes is that the react context is getting destroyed, and a new one is being created.

That error get's thrown whenever a Native Module is trying to do work, by using the old react context.

Comment: Technically you have answered the question. The real question is how to catch the live reload so the native plugin can be told to clean up. Currently I'm checking CatalystInstance.isDestroyed() before using .emit() but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: You can probably listen to the activity's lifecycle events. You need to register a listener in your module's constructor and then implement `onHostDestroy`
Please have a look at the following docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#listening-to-lifecycle-events

Comment: Those are standard app lifecycle events. They don't relate to live reloading. Believe me I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this: 
[Error Boundary in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Just wrap the error prone code inside the ErrorBoundary component, e.g.

```
<ErrorBoundary><childComponentCausingError></ErrorBoundary>
```

And in the ErrorBoundary component, you could just catch the error in componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {

}

componentDidCatch() is a lifecycle method in React.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. I want to proactively clean up a resource on Live Reload, not catch errors because the resource wasn't cleaned up.